# Is it possible to use TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER in a remote EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, glassfish, ejb, corba

Is it possible to use `TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER` instead of `TransactionManagementType.BEAN` in a remote EJB implementation?

For further clarification, I don't want to deal with `begin` and `roolback` methods in my busines layer but I didn't find another way to make it work.

I'm using Glassfish 5 and `corbaname:iiop` protocol to access my remote EJB.

Example of usage:

This code block runs on my server:

```
package br.com;
@Remote
interface IRemote {void method();}

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
class Remote implements IRemote { 
@Resource
private UserTransaction ut;

void method(){
    try{
        ut.begin();
        <my business logic>
        ut.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){...}
}
```

And this code block runs in an app on my local machine:

```
@Stateless
class LocalBean {
    @EJB(mappedName = "corbaname:iiop:myserver.com:3700#java:global/RemoteApp/Remote!br.com.IRemote"
    private IRemote remote;
}
```

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/glassfish-to-glassfish-remote-ejb-invocation) from Oracle but it uses `TransactionManagementType.BEAN` without any explaination.

Is there another way to do this without the need of the transaction above?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Container-Managed Transactions

> RequiresNew Attribute If the client is running within a transaction
>   and invokes the enterprise bean’s method, the container takes the
>   following steps:
>
> Suspends the client’s transaction
>
> Starts a new transaction
>
> Delegates the call to the method
>
> Resumes the client’s transaction after the method completes
>
> If the client is not associated with a transaction, the container
>   starts a new transaction before running the method.
>
> You should use the RequiresNew attribute when you want to ensure that
>   the method always runs within a new transaction.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html

Comment: When i use whatever @TransactionAttribute i got the error on deployment "Method level transaction attributes may not be specified on a bean with transaction type [Bean]. Please see server.log for more details."

Comment: And when i don't use @TransactionAttribute i got the exception in runtime "TransactionRequiredException" when i perform a persist operation

Comment: Transaction attributes can only be used in CMTs: See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html "The TransactionAttribute annotation...can only be specified if container managed transaction demarcation is used."

Answer (score 0):

By default (from the EJB spec) a session bean use ContainerManagedTransaction and Required if there is no annotation.
This should work remote or local.

Also you can do it explicit

```
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Required
public class MyBean ... {
   @Supported  // override class level annotaion
   public void method(...) {
   }
}
```

From the error message above I suppose you try to use the TMType.BEAN but added a @Required or so to the method, this is suppressed by container as the combination is not allowed!

Comment: When i use `@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)`, I got a exception in client: `javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.SecurityException ... Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.rollback(TransactionM‌​anagerImpl.java:376)` –

Comment: About the @Required and @Supported i didn't find the classes... I use maven project with `<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `@TransactionManagement`-Annotation completely from your remote bean, then it defaults to CMT. The usage of `UserTransaction` will then be illegal. So you have to remove that as well, but that was the point, no?

But be aware: you might create remote transactions which means that the two containers might synchronize using XA-Protocol. If you don't want that, define the `TransactionAttribute` to `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW`, then you will have the same behavior as before, without explicite user-transactions.

Comment: When i remove @TransactionManagement, I got a exception in client: 

javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.SecurityException
...
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
 at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.rollback(TransactionManagerImpl.java:376)

Comment: I don't think that the SecurityException is related to CMT, probably: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844092/container-managed-transactions-can-not-rollback) just catch it, or solve the cause of it. Perhaps you can show the full message and stacktrace